# Laravel 5.5 - Missing required parameters for [Route:]

Tags: laravel

What I'm trying to achieve is very simple, but I'm just making this a lot harder than it needs to be. So am seeking help for what is apparently, my lack of Laravel experience.

All I want to do is have a form that can update database entries via a text input. This has to be dynamic as it's being used for a few databases and I don't want to have multiple files for them.

Sorry in advance for the probable messy/crap code...

Here's the routes I have:

```
Route::get('/server/{server}/players/{playerID}/greeting', 'PlayerProfileController@greeting');
Route::post('/server/{server}/players/{playerID}/greeting', 'PlayerProfileController@updateGreeting')->name('greeting.update');
```

The PlayerProfileController

```
  // Display greeting message
  public function greeting($server, $playerID) {
    $greetInfo = DB::connection($server)
    ->table('clients')
    ->where('id', $playerID)
    ->first();

    return view('servers.greeting')
    ->with('greetInfo', $greetInfo);
  }

  // Update greeting message
  public function updateGreeting(Request $request, $server, $playerID) {
      $gUpdate = DB::connection($server)
        ->table('clients')
        ->where('id', $playerID)
        ->update(['greeting' => $request->input('greet')]);

      return back()->with('success', 'Greeting updated successfully!');
  }
```

And finally the form

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => ['PlayerProfileController@updateGreeting', $greetInfo->greeting],  'method' => 'POST']) }}
  {{ Form::bsText('greet', '', ['placeholder' => 'Update greeting or leave blank to remove current message']) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}
  <br>
  {{ Form::bsSubmit('Update',['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary']) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you in advace.

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with your current set up?

Comment: The first issue I can see is the fact that you're set up form with the method `PUT`, but you're registering route to listen for a `post` request type.

Comment: @SebastianSulinski ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Missing required parameters for [Route: greeting.update] [URI: server/{server}/players/{playerID}/greeting]. (View: /var/www/asgard/resources/views/servers/greeting.blade.php) is the error message i get

Comment: You are getting this error exception because you only pass one argument `['PlayerProfileController@updateGreeting', $greetInfo->greeting]` and expect two on your route definition. I would probably suggest using `route()` helper - let me demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ErrorException` you're seeing is caused by the missing argument for the route you're trying to call. Your route is expecting `server` and `playerId`, wheres you're only sending it `$greetInfo->greeting`.

As you're using named route, my suggestion would be to use `route()` helper like so:

```php
Route::get('/server/{server}/players/{playerID}/greeting', 'PlayerProfileController@greeting');
Route::post('/server/{server}/players/{playerID}/greeting', 'PlayerProfileController@updateGreeting')
    ->name('greeting.update');


class PlayerProfileController extends Controller {

    public function greeting($server, $playerID) {
        $greetInfo = DB::connection($server)
            ->table('clients')
            ->where('id', $playerID)
            ->first();

        return view('servers.greeting')
            ->with('greetInfo', $greetInfo);
    }

    // Update greeting message
    public function updateGreeting(Request $request, $server, $playerID) {
        $gUpdate = DB::connection($server)
            ->table('clients')
            ->where('id', $playerID)
            ->update(['greeting' => $request->input('greet')]);

        return back()->with('success', 'Greeting updated successfully!');
    }

}

{{ Form::open(['action' => route('greeting.update', [$server, $playerId]),  'method' => 'post']) }}

    {{ Form::bsText('greet', '', ['placeholder' => 'Update greeting or leave blank to remove current message']) }}

    {{ Form::bsSubmit('Update',['class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary']) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Please replace `$server` and `$playerId` variables with the ones representing the arguments you want to send with the request.

You can see I've also removed `{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }}`, as this was trying to overwrite the `post` method on the `Form::open` method.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to fix some of the issues, still throwing an error. Somehow it's calling the entire URL from the route "Action App\Http\Controllers\http://url.com/server/snd/players/2/greeting not defined. (View: /var/www/asgard/resources/views/servers/greeting.blade.php)

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure I can distinguish between comment and the actual error - could you highlight the actual error message using back ticks?

Comment: Sorry, rookie mistakes: `"Action App\Http\Controllers\url.com/server/snd/players/2/greeting not defined. (View: /var/www/asgard/resources/views/servers/greeting.blade.php`

Comment: When you view source of the page with the form - what do you see as being set for the `action` attribute of the form?

Comment: It doesn't get that far, it doesn't load the page with the form on it. Just throws that error above.

Comment: Can you show me what you've replaced the arguments for the route with in `route('greeting.update', [$server, $playerId])` ?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, it works a treat now. Thanks for your help